# Tensorflow Objection Detection API: Accessing all class scores for a given bounding box?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Using Tensorflow's objection detection API, it is possible to train an SSD inception object detector and perform inference by querying the tensors `detection_boxes:0`, `detection_scores:0`, and `detection_classes:0` corresponding to an array of bounding box coordinates, an array containing the maximum score for each bounding box, and an array of integers corresponding to the maximum score class label of each bounding box, respectively.

What I am interested in are the scores of all classes for each bounding box. First, I tried to see if maybe the `detection_scores` operation had more than one tensor but querying `detection_scores:1` tensor threw an error saying the tensor does not exist. Second, I have tried looking through the node names of the model to find a relevant sounding operation:tensor to query but the names tend to be quite generic. Does anyone know a way to query these values?

(P.S. I am working in python 2.7 with tensorflow-gpu 1.5 and ssd inception v2)

Comment: did you ever find the solution to this? I'm in a need of this too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answer will be satisfactory but lets give it a try:

You can load the model and save it for inspection in tensorboard:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.summary import summary

# I used mobilenet v2 with ssdlite from the tf model zoo
with tf.gfile.FastGFile('frozen_inference_graph.pb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

sess = tf.Session()

sess.graph.as_default()
tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

pb_visual_writer = summary.FileWriter('.')
pb_visual_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

In tensorboard you will see the model, the closest thing I could find to what you are searching for is the `concat` and `concat_1` ops after the `BoxPredictor`s.

The first one outputs a Tensor of shape `?x1917x1x4`, which contains the boxes.
The other outputs a Tensor of shape `?x1917x91`, which contains the scores for each classes for each box.

Note that `concat`is followed by a `Squeeze` op to make it `?x1917x4` and `concat_1` is followed by a sigmoid called  `Postprocessor/convert_scores`

Comment: Oops, I completely forgot that mobilenet ssd exists. I edited the question to clarify that I am working with ssd inception v2. Thanks for your response, I am going to see if I can follow these steps and find something similar in the ssd inception model.